# Read-Only connection to existing h2 database

Tags: database, connection, database-connection, h2

Is is possible open a second connection to an existing h2 database even though another application already has a connection open with locking enabled (LOCK **not** set to NO in URL)?

Let's say I have no control over how the first application connects and nothing can be changed there but I wanna do a select on two tables.